# jquery/css changing css on jquery show in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I've made a hover function with jquery. All works fine in FireFox and Chrome, the problem is in IE. I change the css top/left and use jquery.show to make the div visible. Though in IE the first time you hover it, it shows at the wrong position. Second time it shows just fine..

```
var x = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - $(this).next("div").width();
var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;



$(this).next("div").css({ display: 'block', 'position': 'fixed', zIndex: 2, left: x, top: y });

$(this).next("div").show("slow");
```

Again it works great in Chrome and Firefox, but IE..(I only tested IE9)

this is the CSS the div's have by default to hide it:

```
display:none;
position:fixed;
z-index:2;
```

Comment: Why not add to the next div a class and give a css class definition to that class in the `css` file?

Comment: Initially it has a css class(Shows it as display:none etc), but I don't know. I just did it this way. is there any difference in the way IE takes .css and addClass?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/gup8u/.  Can you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Yes let me Fiddle my complete solution. How long does Fiddle hold it? Like can I delete it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into this problem because the div hasn't fully loaded when you calculate `x`.  jQuery doesn't know what the width of the div will be and thus returns 0.  The next time, of course, the div has loaded, and jQuery gets the width right.

You can correct this by setting `right` instead of `left`.  This improves the animation as well, in my opinion:

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/gup8u/22/

```
$('.linkin').hover(function(e) {
    var x = document.documentElement.offsetWidth - e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;

    $(this).next("div").css({
        right: x,
        top: y
    }).stop(true, true).show("slow");
},
function() {
    $(this).next().addClass('tooltip').stop(true, true).hide("slow");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work indeed! IE is shit slow then, FF and Chrome did it just fine

Comment: @QuincyJones - It didn't work in Chrome or Firefox for me.  Chrome behaved like IE: http://imgur.com/G21wz.  Firefox *never* got it right, usually the div was centered over the thumbnail, sometimes it was way off to the left, but never lined up to the left of the thumbnail as it should.  It was equally slow in firefox and IE for me.  Chrome was just a little bit faster.